# UITabBarController selectedIndex not updating after app returns from background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I set the index of my UITabBarController programmatically:

```
public func SelectTab(index: Int) {
    if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = index
    }
}
```

It works fine unless the app goes to the background. Once the app returns from the background, this no longer works. The tabBarController is still set to the correct index, but the UI no longer updates with the new View Controller.

I can tap a tab bar item, and it updates. However, changing the index programmatically with the above code no longer works.

Is there something else I must do to restore the state of the UITabBarController?

Comment: You need to call in main thread. DispatchQueue.main.asyn{}

Comment: Also when coming back from background, call select tab() in viewWillAppear()

Comment: Where and how is `tabBarController` defined?

Comment: E.Coms The call is already in main thread and works before the app is backgrounded, stops working once the app returns to foreground.

Comment: Mike Taverne It's set up in the main storyboard, and registered to the tabBarController var when the UITabBarController loads. It's not nil when we return, and the address in memory is the same. I can see it still has the 5 child view controllers assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution for this. In case anyone else struggles with it, the problem was in the way I was returning from background. I was reloading the root view, which seemed to work fine until I tried to select the tab.

PROBLEM: I was reloading the main view in applicationWillEnterForeground:

```
let home = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
self.window?.rootViewController = home
```

SOLUTION: In applicationDidEnterBackground, I dismissed all the of the presented controllers above the root view:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Then, in applicationWillEnterForeground, I simply selected the tab:

```
 SelectTab(index: 0)
```

Now everything works as expected.